# How to use VNC on HTTP

Tags: ubuntu, vnc

I work in MNC, where software developers don't have access to Gmail because it is not Corporate mail, Nabble or many other forums, (Can you believe it??? :| )..

So, I want to access my home computer from office.. 
I want to setup VNC server as well as VNC viewer as a web-app on the same computer at home.. And access it from office computer.. using HTTP .. as a true web application.. (I don't mind slow page update rate)

is there any ready made solution??? 
Cheers..

Comment: as an aside, I wonder if the free logmein would work? Be a bit more secure than opening your home firewall to port 80 as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can start the VNC server using port 80.
Depending on your O/S and VNC version, this might be as simple as:

> vncserver -httpport 80

You can also, using Java, access this "web server" from outside to see your screen, via :

> http://your_vncserver

You would need to open the port 80 in your firewall to the server, and probably use a Dynamic DNS Service such as dyndns.org.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use TeamViewer , because "By default TeamViewer uses only the outgoing port 80 (HTTP) - no firewall configuration is necessary".

Or a [web proxy](https://superuser.com/questions/44748/what-free-web-proxies-do-you-find-most-usable/)

Answer (score 0):

To telebog,
Team viewer is not allowed to use from our office... (policy) but VNC is allowed as it is used internally as well as they blocked external access.. 
And my machine is Ubuntu.. Team viewer .. is for windows.